# PowerEdge 2950 hard disk

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge

I am currently trying to determine whether there are any bigger hard drives available for the PowerEdge 2950 (greater than 1TB). Using our tag and Dell's side and google I could only establish a maximum size of 1TB. Is this really the maximum size? Any feedback would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you contacted Dell support?

Comment: Tried to but there website crashed. That's why I am here ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have spoken to Dell and they said that the maximum size is 2TB.

Answer (score 3):

The 2Tb limitation is actually a limitation of the PERC5i/6i cards fitted to the 2950.

Some of the later PERC's (e.g. H700/H800) support larger drives, but then the 2950 does not have a UEFI BIOS so it wouldn't be able to boot from a volume larger than 2Tb anyway, and use of those cards also isn't supported in the 2950.

Answer (score 1):

Nearline SAS drives will work in the 2950 and give you the expanded capacity (up to 3TB) you may be looking for.

Hope that helps.